# Lost menu bars on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I have no menu bars at top or bottom, not sure how to get them back!

Answer (score 0):

Is autohide on ? Move the mouse pointer to the top/bottom of the screen, hold it there for a while. If it pops u, right click -> Disable Autohide.

Otherwise try adding the new panel by right clicking and choosing Create new panel.

You might want to run `xfce4-panel &` in the terminal and see if that helps.